# How do I write a closure in Clojure that maintains state?

Tags: javascript, clojure, closures

I want to write a closure in Clojure to simulate the following JavaScript code:

```
var nextOdd = function () {
    var x = 1;
    return function () {
        var result = x;
        x += 2;
        return result;
    }
}();
nextOdd(); //1
nextOdd(); //3
nextOdd(); //5
```

I know that Clojure supports closures so I could potentially write something like

```
(defn plusn [x]
    (fn [y] (+ x y)))
(def plus2 (plusn 2))
(plus2 3)
```

But I need something that will maintain state (i.e. the state of the next odd) every time I call the function... and then there's the whole immutability thing in Clojure...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is equivalent in clojure

```
(def next-odd (let [x (atom -1)]
                (fn []
                  (swap! x + 2))))

(next-odd)
-> 1
(next-odd)
-> 3
(next-odd)
-> 5
(next-odd)
...
```

Adding to dAni's example if you need odd number sequence:

```
(def odd-numbers (iterate (partial + 2) 1))

(take 5 odd-numbers)
-> (1 3 5 7 9)
```

Answer (score 6):

mobyte answer is correct, but how you tried to solve your problem with an infinite lazy sequence of odds? `(take 10 (filter odd? (range)))`. Perhaps you don't need state.

Comment: thought of that, but that's not the problem I'm trying to solve. What I need is a function that returns something different every time I call it (without having to give it any parameters).